# Intellisense configuration in VS2012 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have two question concerning the autofill (IntelliSense) configuration in VS2012:

When I type `object` and then `.` in QtCreator for example, it automatically recognizes, if `object` is a pointer or not. So when I type the following (where ptr is a pointer):

```
ptr.
```

it automatically shows

```
ptr->
```

so I don't have to type `ptr` + `-` + `>` as I have to in VS2012. Is there a way to change this in VS2012?

Also, when I type `object.si` and autocomplete it to `object.size` then QtCreator automatically completes it to `object.size()` but VS2012 makes me type the `(` and `)` myself. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I know Visual Assist provides the first correction and I believe it will provide the second one too. http://www.wholetomato.com/ It's not free, but the productivity boost should make it worthwhile for a company ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want is not possible. According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) your options are rather limited.

In fact for VS 2012 and later, "IntelliSense Options" are even more sparse and it's information reduced to a small section in [this newer MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hcw1s69b.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is simply to be reminded that what you thought was a solid object is a pointer, when you type `ptr.` and get no IntelliSense options that is your clue, you can just back up and fix it to `->`. But if you know darn well it's a pointer and just don't like typing so much, you're out of luck.

Similarly for the function if you type `object.size` then move on, you will get red wigglies which will remind you to go back and add the `()`. But if it's just that you don't feel like typing them?  No. Though Visual Studio 2013 will close them for you - if you type `(` it will do the `)` and similarly for `[`, `{`, etc.